# jQuery Params Handler Plugin

Tags: jquery, cordova

I'm using the plugin jquery.mobile.paramsHandler to get parameters from a page of my Phonegap application but when I add the jQuery code of the plugin to my html page, all other functions I define in the javascript part of my page do not work, however when I delete the plugin usage, the functions work perfectly, please help. Here is a samle of my code

`<script type="text/javascript">
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }
    // Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Now safe to use the Cordova API
        checkInternerAccess();
        checkLocationService();
        getPosition();
    }

    // alternative to DOMContentLoaded
    document.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (document.readyState === "complete") {
            getPerviousAddress();
        }
    };

    //Using param handler jQuery to get parameters of the URL
    function getPreviousAddress(){
        $(function () {
            $.mobile.paramsHandler.addPage(
                "images-upload",   // jquery mobile page id which will accept parameters
                ["param1"],       // required parameters for that page
                [],              // optional parameters for that page,
                function (urlVars) {
                    var selectedOrgan = document.getElementById('selectedOrganization');
                    selectedOrgan.value = urlVars.param1;

                }
            );
            $.mobile.paramsHandler.init();
        });
    }

    //These functions do not work
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
    }

    function takePhoto() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onCameraSuccess, onCameraError);
    }
    function onCameraSuccess(imageURL) {
        navigator.notification.alert("onCameraSuccess: " + imageURL);
    }
</script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
    <div data-role="page" id="camera_report">
        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="controlgroup">
                <p style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; padding-bottom:20px">Please Select One Option</p>
                <a href="#images-upload?param1=Tanesco" data-role="button">
                    <img style="float:left" src="imgs/1. TANESCO.jpg" />TANESCO
                </a>
                <a href="#images-upload?param1=Dawasco" data-role="button">
                    <img style="float:left" src="imgs/2. DAWASCO.jpg" />DAWASCO
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="images-upload">
        <div class="home-content" data-role="content">
            <div data-role="controlgroup">
            <div class="images-display">
                <form role="form">
                    <div style="">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="damage" placeholder="Maelezo Kuhusu Uharibifu" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Andika Maelezo Mafupi'">
                            <input type="text" id="longitude" value="" name="current-longitude">
                            <input type="text" id="latitude" value=""  name="current-latitude">
                            <input type="text" id="selectedOrganization" name="param1display">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div>
</body>`

Comment: Welcome to SO and please try to strip down your code to the issue.

Comment: Bsically the issue is, if I define the method 'getPreviousAddress()' as I did there, the rest of the functions i.e 'myFunction(), takePhoto()' and any other function I write do not work, If I remove it, they work.

Comment: I foresee that racing condition is involved.